# What is the meaning of this weird sentence?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0379786/synopsis)

> River apparently picked up the memory from some of the Alliance chiefs
>   who came to see her training and the memory was also triggered by the
>   code advert.

its very confusing, on a  confusion scale of 1-10, I will give this sentence to 10.

What is the meaning of this weird sentence?

Comment: At the top of the page it reads: "The content of this page was created directly by users and has not been screened or verified by IMDb staff." Simply, the synopsis is not well written. Just based off that sentence I also can't tell you concretely what the meaning is.

Comment: Seems like a comma is missing before "and":  "The memory was also triggered by the code advert" is an independent clause". Also, not sure whether "who came to see her training" is essential not to be separated by commas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Background: The character River has psychic abilities (can read thoughts).

Breaking down the sentence:

> River apparently picked up the memory from some of the Alliance chiefs...

She read the minds of some Alliance chiefs. Which Alliance chiefs?

> ...the Alliance chiefs who came to see her training...

and also

> ...and the memory was also triggered by the code advert.

There was a code in an advert that also triggered her memory.